# Populate Table In Word Document Template C#

Tags: c#, templates, ms-word, populate

Does anyone know a good way to open a word document template and populate the table in it via C# programming?

Answer (score 3):

If it was me this is what I would use

[DOCX](http://docx.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Best option (for the docx format at least) is
http://docx.codeplex.com/

On the below blog post you can find code samples comparing a very simple document manipulation with DocX, Microsoft's OOXML API and the classic Office Interop libraries:
http://cathalscorner.blogspot.com/2010/06/cathal-why-did-you-create-docx.html

Comment: i have pre-made tables in the template file, I'm not sure docx has the function to populate that pre-made table.

Comment: absolutely, when you use the DocX.Load function to read an existing document, the resulting document object has a Tables list that you can use to manipulate data in the cells. More info here (it's for creating tables, but it shows the objects I am talking about)  http://cathalscorner.blogspot.com/2010/06/docx-and-tables.html

Answer (score 0):

if you are interested in commercial products and work with DOCX file format, you can try our [GemBox.Document](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/overview) component.

It has its own reading / writing engine and simple content model and can be used without MS Word installed.

Here is a sample C# code how to create a simple template document with a table that will be expanded with data using a mail merge functionality:

```
// Use the component in free mode.
ComponentInfo.SetLicense("FREE-LIMITED-KEY");

// Define DataTable with two columns: 'Name' and 'Surname', and fill it with some data.
// You don't have to do this if you already have a DataTable instance.
var dataTable = new DataTable("People")
{
    Columns =
    {
        new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("Surname", typeof(string))
    },
    Rows =
    {
        new object[] { "John", "Doe" },
        new object[] { "Fred", "Nurk" },
        new object[] { "Hans", "Meier" },
        new object[] { "Ivan", "Horvat" }
    }
};

// Create and save a template document. 
// You don't have to do this if you already have a template document.
// This code is only provided as a reference how template document should look like.
var document = new DocumentModel();
document.Sections.Add(
    new Section(document,
        new Table(document,
            new TableRow(document,
                new TableCell(document,
                    new Paragraph(document, "Name")),
                new TableCell(document,
                    new Paragraph(document, "Surname"))),
            new TableRow(document,
                new TableCell(document,
                    new Paragraph(document,
                        new Field(document, FieldType.MergeField, "RangeStart:People"),
                        new Field(document, FieldType.MergeField, "Name"))),
                new TableCell(document,
                    new Paragraph(document,
                        new Field(document, FieldType.MergeField, "Surname"),
                        new Field(document, FieldType.MergeField, "RangeEnd:People")))))));
document.Save("TemplateDocument.docx", SaveOptions.DocxDefault);

// Load a template document.
document = DocumentModel.Load("TemplateDocument.docx", LoadOptions.DocxDefault);

// Mail merge template document with DataTable.
// Important: DataTable.TableName and RangeStart/RangeEnd merge field names must match.
document.MailMerge.ExecuteRange(dataTable);

// Save the mail merged document.
document.Save("Document.docx", SaveOptions.DocxDefault);
```